# Android - Gestures dont's want to work

Tags: android, gestures

I ran Gestures Builder app, created gestures file for slide left/right and wrote this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGesturePerformedListener {

    private GestureLibrary mGestureLibrary;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        GestureOverlayView gestureOverlayView = new GestureOverlayView(this);
        View inflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        gestureOverlayView.addView(inflate);
        gestureOverlayView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
        mGestureLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
        if (mGestureLibrary == null) {
            finish();
        }

        setContentView(gestureOverlayView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mGestureLibrary.recognize(gesture);

        for (Prediction prediction : predictions) {
            if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

gestures are in /raw/, but the app says nothing when I try to test it (it loads gesture successfully, the event onGesturePerformed is called, but the gestures are not recognized). The gestures work perfectly in Gestures Buileder, so where is my mistake?

Comment: By any chance did you figure out the solution to your problem? I am having the same exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to still check the name of the prediction which should match the name of one of your actions. Test for equality and then perform your logic:

```
String action = predictions.get(0).name;
 if("right".equals(action){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call load() on mGestureLibrary before using it. Not that it's documented at all, but that's what Lars does in this example and it works for me: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html

In the IDE you should be able to see entries in the GestureStore HashMap (mNamedGestures).